# Joining, but not joining (hypothetical q.)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets suppose that I have a table A with couple of columns. I work with tables, where there is no index on the entries, since they are 'historical' tables. I use one specific column, though, to sort of identify my things. Lets call this ID.
If you'd make a query like the one below, sometimes you'd get one line back, other cases a few.

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE ID = '<something>'
```

Lets say I have two more tables, B and C. Both have ID columns, like A.
Also, some of the IDs in A, are also in B OR C. IDs existing in B CANNOT exist in C. And ALL IDs in A EXIST in either B OR C.

B and C contain extra information, which I'd like to join to A at the same SELECT.
My problem is, that they would only provide extra information. I do not want extra lines in my output..

To make it more clear: my selection from A returns a hundred lines of output.
When I left/right/inner join B table, I —probably— will have less lines as output. Same thing with joining C.

AND FINALLY, my question is:
Is there a way to join table B only on those IDs, which exist in B and vice versa? (And it I would want it in the same SELECT.... statement.)

Comment: Selecting from `a left outer join b on ... left outer join c on ...` won't produce any less rows than just selecting from a alone, but it could produce more. Where there are multiple rows in b which match the ID in a, how would you know which row you'd want returned?

Comment: B and C also contain a date column. For each ID, there could be multiple entries, and I always need the latest.

Comment: @ppseprus Can you include data from the tables ?

Comment: so you do not want more outputs than records in A, but you do accept 'duplicate' outputs from table A?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. First, it is really complex and second, I dont have access to it. Its work, but on hypothetical basis, I'd like to solve it.

Comment: Records in A are over tens of thousands. I make a selection for a certain period of time and that will return, lets say, a hundred entries. these are already unique — no duplicates.
All three tables are historical, but I always need just the latest entry per ID.
And using that hundred entry, I have to look for extra infos in B and C. Joining on ID, but with the highest date.

Comment: So far.. this could work with joining just one table (for example B), and I would happily use HAVING.......but in such cases, you loose those result of the selection that are NOT in B, only in A.
Not using a HVAING would result either more than a hundred entries as a result OR not being able to filter for the latest entry in B.

Comment: I wonder if theres some sort of union of B and C, which I could join with A at the same time.....?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems like you should build some left join between A and two "Select MAX"s: one from table B, the other one from table C.

And if you do not want 'duplicate' IDs from table A, a 'group by' on table A should help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want extra lines in your output, you could do something like this:

```
select *
from A join
     (select B.*
      from B
      group by B.id
     ) B
     on A.id = B.id;
```

This would choose arbitrary values from B for each `id` and join them back to `A`.  Is this what you want?